# C++ Outputting the sum and product of a set of numbers

Tags: c++, loops

Beginner C++ student here, first programming class. I am trying to build a program which will accept a set of numbers from the user and output the sum and product of those numbers.
Example:

Enter # of values to compute: 4

Enter number: 2

Enter number: 3

Enter number: 4

Enter number: 0.5

Sum is: 9.5, product is: 12

With what I have so far I get the correct sum, however, the product is zero no matter what I try. I am lost in getting that to work. Any help greatly appreciated.

`#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){


double sum = 0;
double product = 0;
double n;
unsigned numberOfValues;


cout << "Enter number of values to compute: ";
cin >> numberOfValues;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> n;

    sum += n;

    product *= n;

}

cout << "the sum is: " << sum << ", the product is: " << product << endl;

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the value of product to 1 instead of to 0

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! There was a version I wrote where I had initiated that value at 1 but was getting zero regardless, I think I may have had another part of the code setup incorrectly as well at the same time and was completely throwing me off. Thank you for putting me back on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply 0 to start with. Look `product` variable declaration `double product = 0;`

Whatever multiplied by 0 will be 0, basic math.

Comment: Thank you as well. I was doing some other stuff incorrectly when initializing that value to 1 which was also throwing me off and confusing me. Got this far and wasn't sure what was happening anymore. Gotta be more careful. Thank you!

Comment: I answered the question first, would be nice if you could mark mine as the correct answer :(